# Improve efficiency of data traversal in PieCloudDB

Tags: performance, traversal

As the volume of PieCloudDB Database grows, and if there are an increasing number of tables, both wide and small, along with numerous chunk objects stored in S3, how can we improve the efficiency of data traversal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PieCloudDB Database allows users to specify the block_size when creating tables, and users can customize the configuration according to their actual needs. Additionally, PieCloudDB employs optimization techniques such as block skipping during file scanning, all of which can enhance data traversal efficiency.